# The closure month column should display only from the current month and not the past month?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

[image: Reference]I need a validations formula to display only from the current month and not the past month [[image: Reference]]

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Is this lookup values or hard-coded dropdown values?

Comment: This question is at risk of being flagged unless more detail is provided. Please be more articulate in describing the functionality you are trying to achieve and provide more specific detail on what you have tried so far (i.e specify what column type you are using and if there is any formula etc)

Comment: It is a Hard-coded drop-down values ,

Comment: Now i have added it for your reference

Comment: You can write javascript code and put in on new & edit forms. In JS code you can compare current month with months in dropdown and remove earlier months.
I suggest to use moment.js to work with dates. JS skills needed.

Comment: Can anyone help me with the script ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below formula for your field(the option should keep same format,Jan 2018 is different format).

```
=CONCATENATE(TEXT(NOW(),"mmm"),"-",TEXT(NOW(),"YYYY"))
```

[image]

Sample result.

[image]

Comment: But it only display Current month !! I need a validation if user select the past month its should not allow the user and prompt a msg to select from the current month

Comment: You could use presaveaction for client side validation, https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sagarp/use-of-presaveaction-function-on-list-forms-in-sharepoint-20/

Comment: Is there anything we can do with column validations instead of presaveaction! ?

Comment: Not easy to compare the Month by formula.